# Problems transforming QString to _bstr_t

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to transform a QString to _bstr_t type as follows:

QString mFilename="C:/agatebo/amahoro.doc";

```
    QByteArray srcBa1 = mFilename.toLocal8Bit();
    const char *srcString1 = srcBa1.data();
    CString myStringSrc(srcString1,srcBa1.size());

    BSTR bstrUser = myStringSrc.AllocSysString();

    _bstr_t user(bstrUser,TRUE);
```

but when I pass the _bstr_t I get to this function:

```
pdfObject->cPrintFile(user);
```

PDFCreator ,a program whose COM interface I am using just crashes .I suspect this has something to do with unicode but can’t figure out what yet.I should mention that when I directly pass a path to the file like this:

```
 pdfObject->cPrintFile(L"c:\\agatebo\\amahoro.doc");
```

all is ok ,I simply want to be able to use QStrings that come from other modules of my Qt application.I am compiling with Qt 4.8 msvc2010 if this matters. I would appreciate any

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use QString.utf16()

```
void ProcedureThatTakesWChar(const wchar_t* s) {
  std::wcout<<s<<L'\n';
}

void ProcedureThatTakesBstr(const BSTR& s) {
  std::wcout<<s<<L'\n';
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QString qs("this is a qstring");

    //pass directly
    ProcedureThatTakesWChar(qs.utf16());


    //if you really want to use a _b_str initialise it with .utf16()
    //_b_str will handle SysAllocString and SysFreeString. QString
    //does not have to stay in scope.
    {
      _bstr_t bs(qs.utf16());
      ProcedureThatTakesBstr(bs);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried the one with ProcedureThatTakesBstr(bs); and it is throwing me file cannot be found errors.

Comment: This is a pretty vague problem description. You mean the code compiles and runs, but you get an error at runtime? If so I would need to know a lot more about what you are trying to do in order to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on Windows and the method call works when you pass in a wide string, that means you're compiling in Unicode mode.  This means that TCHAR,_bstr_t etc. are typedefed to wchar_t.  You can learn more about Unicode support in Windows [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dax2h36.aspx).

The good news is that QString and Microsoft's Unicode implementation both use the same character encoding, [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

To get the raw QString data you simply call QString's [utf16() method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#utf16).  This returns a pointer to an array of null-terminated unsigned shorts -- the same type as wchar_t on Windows!

So in all you should have to do here is this:

```
pdfObject->cPrintFile(mFilename.utf16());
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion.The program doesn't crash but It is throwing errors saying the file can't be found.

Comment: Here is my error log  in case it might help
ERROR DESCRIPTION:
          Error-Nr: 76 (Path not found)
          Modul: modGeneral
          Procedure: GetFiles
          Line:      50370
          Date/Time: 2015-02-08 / 15:19:17

CALLSTACK:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
SYSTEMINFO:
 Windows 7 6.1 Build 7601 (Service Pack 1)
  [TerminalServer IsWinXPPlus IsWinVistaPlus IsWinVistaSP1 IsWindows7]

Comment: @musimbate This sounds like an unrelated problem/new question.